# why isn't XSL translate working?

Tags: debugging, xslt

Forgive me, I'm new to XSL, but this doesn't seem to be working:

```
call <a><xsl:attribute name="HREF">callto:translate(<xsl:value-of select="phone"/>, ' -().:', '')</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="phone"/></a>
```

The XML is

```
<phone>(555)-123-4567</phone>
```

And the page output is

```
call <a href="callto:translate((555)-123-4567, ' -().:', '')">(555)-123-4567</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the translate function inside the `<xsl:value-of` tag. Here's the code, fixed:

```
call <a><xsl:attribute name="HREF">callto:<xsl:value-of select="translate(phone, ' -().:', '')"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="phone"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
call <a HREF="callto:{translate(phone, ' -().:', '')}">
```